# Pass Bitmap to another activity but getting error FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION

Tags: android, bitmap

Hello friends i want to pass bitmap from one activity to another activity. i did it successfully but my problem is that when bitmap is passed to another activity it giving error of FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION. Please friends please help me to resolve this problem.
I am using below code to pass image to another activity

```
     Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

       if(selectedImageUri!=null){

                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageCropperActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("mpath", selectedImagePath);
                startActivity(i);
```

and i am getting bitmap like this.

```
 if(imagePath != null){
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image path " +imagePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //imgCrop.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
        mImageUri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("mpath"));
        mFileTemp = new File(getIntent().getStringExtra("mpath"));
    }
```

please friends please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: This code is not passing a bitmap. It is passing a `Uri`. While passing a bitmap can be a problem due to size, a `Uri` should not be a problem. You have a ~1 MB limit for the size of the `Intent`, including its extras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to compress bitmap first and then pass it to next activity

Compress using this

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray(); 
    setresult.putExtra("BMP",bytes);
```

Uncompress using this code

```
 byte[] bytes = data.getByteArrayExtra("BMP");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

---Note---

```
There are some limitations as to how much data a bundle can contain. If your bundle or intent extras are too large you can get FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION error.
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Hello imtiyaz sir here data means Bundle's object?